# Normalizing raster using raster calculator raises TypeError

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, error-000539, normalize

In ArcGIS 10.1 I'm trying to normalize a section of a DEM (digital elevation model) from original values to values ranging from 0 to 100. First I clipped the raster DEM with an irregulary shaped polygon.
Now I'm tying to change all the values to a range of 0 to 100 for further analysis.

I'm using the Raster calculator tool with this equation:

```
("DEM" - min("DEM")) * 100 / (max("DEM") - min("DEM")) + 0
```

I keep getting TypeError: 'Raster' object not iterable. This is the log I get:

```
   ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
    TypeError: 'Raster' object is not iterable
```

I also tried running the command on the unclipped raster, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The builtin python [`min()` and `max()` functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) operate only on python [iterables](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) (i.e lists, tuples, etc.) and return the smallest/largest item in the iterable. They do not return the minimum/maximum value of a Raster object which is why a `TypeError` was raised.

You need to use the [`Raster.minimum` and `Raster.maximum`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) properties.

For example:

```
("dem" -"dem".minimum) * 100 / ("dem".maximum - "dem".minimum) + 0
```

Note: This will work as long as you have already [calculated statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) for the raster, otherwise it will fail as `"raster".minimum` will return `None`.